# new Date() converts timezone

Tags: javascript, date

Why is `new Date()` converting the timezone? I'd like my date to be the same as the string I provide, so `00:30` and not `10:30`.

```
>>> new Date("2015-04-11T00:30:00");
Sat Apr 11 2015 10:30:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
```

Comment: Because the date constructor runs in your browser, and uses whatever time and timezone is set on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

You passed the date in ISO form into the constructor "2015-04-11T00:30:00".
That means your browser interprets that not as local time but as UTC. Date.toString however uses your local time. If you want to use UTC time call .toUTCString or better yet .toISOString.

Comment: Learned something new! Deleted my answer, please comment with an informative source if you got one.

Comment: Here is the MDN documentation on Date. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date  and something about ISO time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: When doing new Date() in the javascript console, the browser will automatically call .toString on the created object and toString looks at your local time zone. If there is confusion over what time a given Date object really represents, I suggest to always call the .toISOString method. In fact even if there is no confusion you should always use toISOString or toJSON when working with dates.