# DateTimePicker converts timezone , Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone

```
import DateTimePicker from 'react-widgets'
import Moment from 'moment'
import momentLocalizer from 'react-widgets-moment';
```

DateTimePicker field contains "Wed Jan 16 2018 **23:53:32**". (My timezone GMT+02)

But when I send request :
`date = 2018-01-16T21:53:32.919Z`

Comment: A `Date` object doesn't have a time zone - its simple string representation uses the local time zone, but it just represents an instant in time. 2018-01-16T21:53:32.919Z and Wed Jan 16 2018 23:53:32 GMT+0200 are the same instant in time, so it's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: (And note that GMT+0200 and GMT+00 are different...)

Comment: I mean I send 23:53.
But receive 21:53

Comment: 23:53 at an offset of UTC+2 is the same as 21:53 UTC. They're the same instant in time.

Comment: Yes, because the two timestamps use different time zones, but they represent the same moment in time.

Comment: @befev—how to fix what? Perhaps see [*new Date() converts timezone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577879/new-date-converts-timezone). Note that what the console prints and what *Date.prototype.toString* return may be different (consoles aren't standardised), and the value of [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is entirely implementation dependent.

Comment: If you want the Date in a specific format, see [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript) It is common to exchange time stamps as ISO 8601 UTC as a *de facto* standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***DateTimePicker*** is not converting timezone at all. It saves values as a ***Data Object***.

The reason was in the `Axios` library, which does JSON.stringify() for the data object.

JSON.stringify() tries to call **toJSON**() method, so as the result Date is converted to string with ISO-8601 standard.

On the other hand, if try to display Date Object as a string (e.g. console.log()), method **toString**() will be automatically called, what represents the value in local timezone.